# How to declare instance variables in ABC which implementations could have different types

Tags: python, abstract-class, instance-variables, mypy, python-typing

I have an `ABC` that there will be an instance variable, let's say `record` in all of its implementation classes. For readability, I want to let readers know the instances of that `ABC` are supposed to have a `record` instance variable.

However, the type of `record` varies in different implementation classes. And I want to avoid having my `ABC` specify all the possible types that `record` could use (e.g. `record: DjangoModelA | DjangoModelB` in ABC) because this sounds very not right to me.

Here is a simple version of my current code:

```py
class Abstract(ABC):
    record: None

class SubA(Abstract):
    record: DjangoModelA

class SubB(Abstract):
    record: DjangoModelB
```

which mypy complains:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "DjangoModelA", base class "Abstract" defined the type as "None")
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "DjangoModelB", base class "Abstract" defined the type as "None")
```

How should I declare the abstract base class to make mypy and me happy with it?

Answer (score 0):

Will the `record` always be the django model? If so, I suppose you can try:

```
from django.db import models
class Abstract(ABC)
    record: models.Model
```